# Datetime format in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date

Using Rails, I need to add the html tag:

```
<time datetime="2012-04-29T16:58Z">20 days ago</time>
```

From a stored date. How do I get the above from @post.created_at?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm stuck in the date format in Rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See strftime http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime

```
<%= @post.created_at.strftime(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ) %>
<%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %>
```

Comment: You do understand me! Thank you. Although I had some problems with "translation missing: es.datetime.distance_in_words.about_x_hours", but I solved it.